# Return the model class in an OOP way

Tags: php, oop

I have a redundant method `q()` on all of my classes which inherit a certain parent class.

The method `q()` always returns the model of the sub class. See code snippet:

```
class Record1 extends AR
{
     public static function q()
     {
         return self::model(__CLASS__)
     }
}

class Record2 extends AR
{
     public static function q()
     {
         return self::model(__CLASS__)
     }
}
```

I'm planning to move the `q` method in the parent class AR. I'm thinking of using `get_called_class` but it does not detect the sub class when I'm trying to access it in the parent class.

The 2 classes are AR classes for a MySQL database.

To query tables I will be doing something like this:

```
$record1 = Record1::q()->findAll()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: "when I'm trying to access it in the parent class" - how? And what is this supposed to be, a factory method? A little context would help to find the "OOP way"

Comment: @fschmengler Updated the question. I can explain it that way. Not sure on how to go about on putting more context to this. my apologies.

Comment: FWIW A static method to return a static class name to call a static method to call an instance method is not OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late Static Binding is a way to achieve this. You are using it by get_called_class function. As of PHP 5.5 you can also use "static::class" to get the name of the called class. Your method could look like that with "static::class":

```
class AR
{
    public static function q() {
        return self::model(static::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! lesser code than using get_called_class function thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly guessing, you probably want to use 'static'. E.g.

```
class A {
    static $a = 'a';

    public static function c() {
            return static::$a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static $a = 'b';
}

/*
 * string(1) "a"
 * string(1) "b"
 */
var_dump(A::c());
var_dump(B::c());
```

You'll get two 'a's if you use self in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this since `get_called_class` is possible anyway.

```
class AR
{
   public static function q()
   {
       $className = get_called_class();
       return $className::model($className);
   } 
}
```

I'm still open for other answers.